# Why is my index not automatically used?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a table

```
Archive(VarId SMALLINT, Timestamp DATETIME, Value FLOAT)
```

`VarId` is not unique. The table contains measurements. I have a clustered index on `Timestamp`. Now i have the requirement of finding a measurement for a specific VarId before a specific date. So I do:

```
SELECT TOP(1) * 
FROM Archive 
WHERE VarId = 135 
  AND Timestamp < '2012-06-01 14:21:00'
ORDER BY Timestamp DESC;
```

If there is no such measurement this query searches the whole table. So I introduced another index on `(VarId, Timestamp)`.

My problem is: SQL Server doesn't seem to care about it, the query still takes forever. When I explicitly state `'WITH (INDEX = <id>)'` it works as it should. What can I do so SQL Server uses my index automatically?

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Do you have an `order by` or do you actually not care what row you get? What columns do you need in the output? Query just those columns instead of `*` (all columns). If it is just `Value` you want you could try to include value in the index you created (as an included column).

Comment: have you run EXPLAIN on your query?

Comment: If you do a `SELECT *....` the chances that a nonclustered index will be used are miniscule. After all: you want **all** data columns - so the query will need to go to the table data anyway, in the end - so often it's just easier to just do a clustered index scan instead.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Thanks, I've added the order by in my post. I need at least Timestamp and Value. It works when I add Value to my index but this bloats the index quite a bit. This makes the index a complete copy of the original table, right?

Comment: @marc_s Yeah, right. But it only needs to go to the table _once_. The search for the right row takes much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your index design is the issue. You have a CLUSTERED index on a DATETIME field and I suspect that it is not unique data, much like VarId, and hence you did not declare it as UNIQUE. Because it is not unique there is a hidden, 4-byte "uniqueifier" field (so that each row can by physically unique regardless of you not giving it unique data) and the rows with the same DATETIME value are essentially random within the group of same DATETIME values (so even narrowing down a time still requires scanning through that grouping). You also have a NONCLUSTERED index on VarId, Timestamp. NONCLUSTERED indexes include the data from the CLUSTERED index so internally your NONCLUSTERED index is really: VarId, Timestamp, Timestamp (from the CLUSTERED index). So you could have left off the Timestamp column in the NONCLUSTERED index and it would have all been the same to the optimizer, but in a sense it would have been better as it would be a smaller index.

So your physical layout is based on a date while the VarId values are spread across those dates. Hence VarId = 135 can be spread very far apart in terms of data pages. Yes, your non-clustered index does group them together, but the optimizer is probably looking at the fact that you are wanting all fields (the "SELECT *" part) and the Timestamp < '2012-06-01 14:21:00' condition in addition to that seems to get most of what you need as opposed to finding a few rows and doing a bookmark lookup to get the "Value" field to fulfill the "SELECT *". Quite possibly if you do just "SELECT TOP(1) VarId, Timestamp" it would more likely use your NONCLUSTERED index without needing the "INDEX =" hint.

Another issue affecting performance overall could be that the ORDER BY is requesting the Timestamp in DESC order and if you have the CLUSTERED index in ASC order then it would be the opposite direction of what you are looking for (at least in this query). Of course, in that case then it might be ok to have Timestamp in the NONCLUSTERED index if it was in DESC order.

My advice is to rethink the CLUSTERED index. Judging on just this query alone (other queries/uses might alter the recommendation), try dropping the NONCLUSTERED index and recreate the CLUSTERED index with the Timestamp field first, in DESC order, and also with the VarId so it can be delcared UNIQUE. So:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [UIX_Archive_Timestamp_VarId] 
ON Archive (Timestamp DESC, VarId ASC)
```

This, of course, assumes that the Timestamp and VarId combination is unique. If not, then still try this without the UNIQUE keyword.

Update:

To pull all of this info and advice together:

When designing indexes you need to consider the distribution of the data and the use-cases for interacting with it. More often than not there is A LOT to consider and several different approaches will appear good in theory. You need to try a few approaches, profile/test them, and see which works best in reality. There is no "always do this" approach without knowing all aspects of what you are doing and what else is going on and what else is planned to use and/or modify this table which I suspect has not been presented in the original question.

So to start the journey, you are ordering records by date and are looking at ranges of dates AND dates naturally occur in order so putting Timestamp first benefits more of what you are doing and has less fragmentation, especially if defined as DESC in the CREATE. Having an NC index on just VarId at that point will then be fine, even if spread out, for looking at a set of rows for a particular VarId. So maybe start there (change order of direction of CLUSTERED index and remove Timestamp from the NC index). See how those changes compare to the existing structure. Then try moving the VarId field into the CLUSTERED index and remove the NC index. You say that the combination is also not unique but does increase the predictability of the ordering of the rows. See how that works. Does this table ever get updated? If not and if the Value field along with Timestamp and VarId would be unique, then try adding that to the CLUSTERED index and be sure to create with the UNIQUE keyword. See how these different approaches work by looking at the Actual Execution Plan and use SET STATISTICS IO ON before running the query and see how the logical reads between the different approaches compare.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: But then the VarId would still be spread over the whole table and it would take forever to run my query if there actually isn't a measurement that matches my where. Also Timestamp + VarId is not guaranteed to be unique and there is no other reason for adding VarId to the index, right?

Comment: @user232986: You can't optimize for all uses at the same time. Pick operations that are most frequently used or most burdensome on the system. You will have either Timestamp OR VarId spread out physically so pick which is less painful. I updated the answer with more details. I would, however, recommend against having a CLUSTERED index on one column and then creating an NC index on all three. At that point you are better off putting all fields in the CLUSTERED index with Timestamp first and maybe having an NC index on VarId to support queries against VarId that do not filter on Timestamp.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the long delay. My actual question is/was: Why isn't SQL Server using my index when it's a hundred times faster? I kind of expected SQL Server to recognize which queries should use which index.

Comment: That is what we have been trying to answer :). I's not a simple answer; there are MANY factors. SQL Server is weighing many things: the ordering of the index vs what the query wants, doing SELECT * which needs all columns so it has to go back to the table anyway, the fact that you are filtering and ordering on the Cluster key. Sometimes the optimizer is wrong which is why we have the INDEX = hint. My recommendations are about helping the optimizer make better decisions. And sometimes UPDATE STATS helps but if not then look at the index design. Test a few variations to see what works best.

Comment: Okay so I guess I will just go for the query hint. Even if I got the optimizer to choose the right index for the query, there is no guarantee that it will do so with the next version of SQL Server. Thanks for your endurance! :)

Comment: Actually, I still recommend trying some variations on changing the index design / strategy. I don't think this behavior will change with future versions of SQL Server. It really shouldn't hurt to try a few things that I suggested, such as adding VarId to the CLUSTERED index and/or changing the Timestamp order to be DESC. Having Timestamp alone in the CLUSTERED index hurts more and more as additional rows with the same value are added. And are the Timestamp values using milliseconds or only down to the minute or second?

Comment: Milliseconds. By 'same value' do you mean same timestamp? That happens very rarely. Also I still don't understand what adding VarId as second column to my CI should do since Timestamp is almost unique. Making Timestamp order DESC would mean that new measurements would be added at the beginning which is bad performance-wise (at least that's what I've read).

Comment: Yes, was asking about same Timestamp. If SQL Server is determining the time then maybe use the DATETIME2 type (down to the nanosecond) and hence more likely unique. If the timestamp is coming from whatever is inserting VarId and Value then maybe not an option. Regarding adding VarId and/or DESC, just try it. Regarding DESC, if you INSERT 10+ records per second then not optimal, but you have to pick either INSERT or SELECT to optimize for. If your main query is DESC then worth trying. Why not see what works best rather than guess? This is all testable. Don't guess or trust me or blogs: test!

Comment: Okay, I will set up some tests when I have enough spare time. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I certainly understand that there isn't much time to test various scenarios, but unfortunately performance tuning requires testing different ideas. I just did a simple test using the structure you said you have and with 23,000 rows. Using your query above, it did a nonclustered index seek without a hint but also required a key lookup and used 4 logical reads. I dropped both indexes and added the clustered index on Timestamp & VarId (both ASC). It then used just a Clustered Index Seek and only 2 logical reads. Data volume and distribution play a role in index design, hence needing to test ;-).

Answer (score 3):

There are different possibilities with this.
I'll try help you to isolate them:

1. It could be SQL Server is favouring your Clustered Index (very likely it's the Primary Key)  over your newly created index. One way to solve this is to have a NonClustered Primary Key and cluster the index on the other two fields (varid and timestamp). That is, if you don't want varid and timestamp to be the PK.
2. Also, looking at the (estimated) execution plan might help.
3. But I believe #1 only works nicely if those 2 fields are the most commonly used (queried) index. To find out if this is the case, it would be good to analyse which index users are most likely use (from http://sqlblog.com/blogs/louis_davidson/archive/2007/07/22/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats.aspx):

```
  select
          ObjectName = object_schema_name(indexes.object_id) + '.' + object_name(indexes.object_id),
          indexes.name,
          case when is_unique = 1 then 'UNIQUE ' else '' end + indexes.type_desc,
          ddius.user_seeks,
          ddius.user_scans,
          ddius.user_lookups,
          ddius.user_updates
        from
          sys.indexes
        left join sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ddius on (
          indexes.object_id = ddius.object_id
            and indexes.index_id = ddius.index_id
            and ddius.database_id = db_id()
        )

        WHERE
          object_schema_name(indexes.object_id) != 'sys' -- exclude sys objects
            AND object_name(indexes.object_id) LIKE 'Archive'
        order by
          ddius.user_seeks + ddius.user_scans + ddius.user_lookups
        desc
```

Good luck

Comment: I don't have a primary key since it's possible that there are two or more identical measurements. Also I don't think it would be a good idea to have (VarId, Timestamp) as a clustered index since new measurements would be added all over the table. With just (Timestamp) they are generally added at the end of the table. If I understood clustered indexes correctly this is quite important for performance. Another point would be that I often do queries like get all measurements between two dates. Those return a lot of data. I think that's another reason to have the clustered index only on Timestamp.

Comment: ok - it seems you don't want to change the clustered index from Timestamp.

what about using `nonclustered index` with `include` to include columns you need as part of the index ? Remember that this is going to impact write performance, as a trade off to improving read performance.

another idea - to have a clustered index in addition to `Timestamp` is to use Indexed View (depending on the edition of your SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to analyze your table to collect statistics, so the optimizer can determine whether to use the index or not.